Find all solutions $x^3-3x-5\equiv 0 \mod 7^4$
I am trying to solve the following exercise, but something is not working like it should:
Let $f=x^3-3x-5$, find all solutions of $f(x) \equiv 0 \mod 7^4$.
My Approach:
The idea is to solve $f(x) \equiv 0 \mod 7$ and then lift the solution such that $f(x) \equiv 0 \mod 7^2$. Repeating the step two times we will get  $f(x) \equiv 0 \mod 7^4$.
To lift the soltunions I will use the following lemma
Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $x_0 \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $f(x_0) \equiv 0 \mod p^k$ for $k \in  \mathbb{N}$. Further let l \in \mathbb{N} such that $l \leq k$. Then for $a \in \mathbb{Z}$:
$f(x_0+ap^k) \equiv 0 \mod p^{k+l} \Leftrightarrow
f'(x_0)a \equiv \frac{-f(x_0)}{p^k} \mod p^l$
Mod $7$ we get $x^3-3x-5\equiv x^3+4x+2$.
The solution of $x^3+4x+2 \equiv 0 \mod 7$ are $x_1=1$ and $x_2=5$.
Lifting the solution $x_1=1$:
Calculating the derivative: $(x^3+4x+2)'=3x^2+4$
Then by the Lemma we want to find $a$ such that $(3\cdot 1 +4)a \equiv \frac{-f(1)}{7} \mod 7$
I.e. $0 \cdot a \equiv -1 \mod 7$.
There is no solution $a$ such that this holds.
Lifting the solution $x_2=5$:
We want to find $a$ such that:
$(3 \cdot 5^2+4) a \equiv -21 \mod 7$.
I.e.
$2a \equiv 0 \mod 7$, thus we get $a=0$.
So by the Lemma $f(5) \equiv 0 \mod 7^2$.
But $f(5)=105$ and $105 \equiv 7 \mod 7^2$.
Where is the mistake?

$x\equiv2084$ is the only solution

$-f(5)/7= -15\equiv -1 \mod 7$, so $a=3$. Indeed, $f(26) \equiv 0 \mod 49$.

Factoring the polynomial in $\mathbb F_7$ we have $(x+2)(x-1)^2$ so there are the double root $x=1$ and $x=-2=5$. What it remains to finish is a standard way (but long according the exponent of $7$).

You really have two mistakes. First the right side is not $-21$, and second you need a division by $7$.
We proceed slowly. Given $x^3-3x-5\equiv0\bmod7^2$ and $x\equiv5\bmod7$, we render
$(7a+5)^3-3(7a+5)-5\equiv0\bmod7^2$
We expand the binomial power with the Binomial Theorem and note that by construction, all multiples of $7^2$ or a higher power of $7$ are zeroed out $\bmod7^2$. So, as with Hensel's Lemma, we are left with only first and zeroth derivative terms:
$(3×5^2×7a)+(5^3)-(3×3×7a)-(3×5)-5\equiv0\bmod7^2$
$(7a)(3×5^2-3)\equiv(-5^3)+(3×5)+5\bmod7^2$
$(7a)(2)\equiv42\bmod7^2$
So the residue you rendered as $-21\equiv28$ on the right side of your equation is actually $\equiv42$, a different multiple of $7$.
Moreover, you have a factor of $7a$ on the left so to isolate $a$ you must divide out the factor of $7$. Since the modulus has that factor you also divide the modulus by $7$ to get, properly,
$(a)(2)\equiv6\implies a\equiv3\bmod7$
So $x\equiv(3×7+5)\equiv26\bmod7^2$ is predicted to satisfy $x^3-3x-5\equiv0\bmod7^2$, and you can check that it holds.
Based on this analysis I leave subsequent liftings to you.
